# How to remove objects from array with checkbox evaluated to true in angular

Tags: angular

I have simple data model and one component and a template. If someone could help me to make a function which will remove all objects from array with checkbox clicked or evaluated to true.

This is my component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Model } from "./model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My Todo App';
  model = new Model();
  items = this.model.items;
  
}
```

html template

```
<h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>

  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th>Description</th><th>Done</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.action }}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.done" /></td>
    <td [ngSwitch]="item.done">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="true">Yes</span>
    <span *ngSwitchDefault>No</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table> 

    <button (click)='delItem(item.done)'>Remove</button>
```

and data model

```
export class Model{
    items; 

    constructor(){
        this.items = [
            {action:'get up', done:false},
            {action:'eat', done:false},
            {action:'learn', done:false}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by remove all objects? empty the array completely or just remove that one object?

Comment: To be sure. When we check the checkbox button, the data in the array is removed. Is it so?

Comment: I did it I just added filter on model.items like this tnx enyway 
 this.model.items =  this.model.items.filter(item => !item.done)